# Which position is after `wp-load.php`?

Tags: wp-load.php

i.e. instead of this code:

```
include_once(...'/wp-load.php');

add_action('init', 'my');
function my(){
  if(current_user_can('manage_options')){
   .....
  }
}
```

we can simply use:

```
include_once(...'/wp-load.php');
if(current_user_can('manage_options')){
   .....
}
```

and to my surprise, this function works. How it works?   what state is there right after the line  `include(wp-load)` ?  Seems `init` already happened?

Comment: where are you writing this? do you know if include_once is even doing anything?

Comment: @JoelM that is just example. concept is that after including wp-load.